# CMD how to use if and tasklist with find /C

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Anyone knows how to use **IF** and **tasklist** with **find /C**. 
I want to compare running instances or certain application to predefined number.

Application name= test.exe

number of instances that should run=2 (If there are less then do stuff else report OK)

Here is my doo-bey-doo so far:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq test.exe" | find /I /C "test.exe"
```

This works great. I get the correct figure of running instances. But when I put it into IF sentence in a BATCH file that's where the hell breaks loose. So where I go wrong here?

```
if tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq test.exe" | find /I /C "test.exe" EQU 2 : ECHO OK

ELSE ( GOTO doStuff )

:doStuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (' tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq test.exe" ^| find /I /C "test.exe" ') do (
if %%a neq 2 goto :dostuff
)
echo ok
goto :eof
:dostuff
```